# How to work only with the Entity Framework Scaffolded Models from Database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have been working with .Net Core Entity Framework database first approach with the Scaffolding technique.

It generated me a couple Models/Classes from my Database Tables, but for now, I will just minimize the issue I am having to this two tables... a relation one to many on the both ChampionID column:

[image]

So, after scaffolding/mapping the models with EntityCore Tools it generated the following two classes (and several others that are not relevant):

Champion.cs:

```
public partial class Champion
{
    public Champion()
    {
        ChampionScreenshot = new HashSet<ChampionScreenshot>();
        ChampionUser = new HashSet<ChampionUser>();
        ChampionUserRate = new HashSet<ChampionUserRate>();
    }

    public int ChampionId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public byte AttackDamageScore { get; set; }
    public byte AbilityPowerScore { get; set; }
    public byte ResistanceScore { get; set; }
    public byte PlayingDifficult { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryClassId { get; set; }
    public int SecondaryClassId { get; set; }

    public ChampionClass PrimaryClass { get; set; }
    public ChampionClass SecondaryClass { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChampionScreenshot> ChampionScreenshot { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChampionUser> ChampionUser { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChampionUserRate> ChampionUserRate { get; set; }
}
```

ChampionScreenshot.cs:

```
public partial class ChampionScreenshot
{
    public int ChampionScreenshotId { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public int ChampionId { get; set; }

    public Champion Champion { get; set; }
}
```

My doubt is: what is the correct way to retrieve a Champion object with the ChampionScreenshot attribute filled?

For example, this is what I am doing in my Service layer:

```
    public async Task<Champion> GetChampion(int id)
    {
        Champion champion = await _context.Champion.FirstAsync(m => m.ChampionId == id);
        champion.ChampionScreenshot = _context.ChampionScreenshot.ToListAsync().Result.FindAll(m => m.ChampionId == champion.ChampionId);

        return champion;
    }
```

So I am basically getting a specific Champion and then filling the ChampionScreenshot attribute (which is also a Class) separately, but the thing is that inside my ChampionScreenshot there is also a Champion class attribute which fully loads once again:

[image]

Which is obviously generating an error once it is exposed in the endpoint of the Restful Service:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/Champions")]
public class ChampionsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetChampion([FromRoute] int id)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var champion = await _service.GetChampion(id);

        if (champion == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(champion);
    }
    ...
```

Error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Self referencing loop detected for property 'champion' with type 'ChampionsService.Models.Champion'. Path 'championScreenshot[0]'.
```

So, I was thinking in just creating my custom model and fill it with the data extracted from my DbContext instead of returning the models already created but I really think that there should be a way to fully use only the mapped Models, I was wondering that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Champion` references itself:

Champion > multiple ChampionScreenshot > Champion (back to the original object)

That's easy to solve:

```
return Json(champion, new JsonSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore });
```

Or you could do it for the entire application:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opts => 
{
    opts.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
});
```

And then just:

```
return Json(champion);
```

---

The following troubles me, though:

```
Champion champion = await _context.Champion.FirstAsync(m => m.ChampionId == id);
champion.ChampionScreenshot = _context.ChampionScreenshot.ToListAsync().Result.FindAll(m => m.ChampionId == champion.ChampionId);
```

You are saying "go to the database, download every single championscreenshot and find the ones I want through an in-memory search". That's not only horrible slow, it also wastes a lot of resources in your application and in the database. For including data, you use `Include`:

```
Champion champion = await _context.Champion
    .Include(x => x.ChampionScreenshot)
    .FirstAsync(x => x.ChampionId == id);
```

(this says "go to the database and bring me the champion but also include all the ChampionScreenshot that correspond, through an inner join).

Comment: I just love what you did here!, Yeah sorry, I am very new to Lambda stuff, very newbie, I am more used to working with stored procedures rather than handle business logic in the c# layer.

You know, i was about to update the post saying that I did iterate through the List of ChampionScreenshots and set all the Champion inside to null hehe, I mean it did work, but... well you know, such a noob I am. Thanks!

Comment: @JoséCaballero That's fine, we all need to learn at some point! You are welcome, glad to help. By the way, you may want to read [what to do when you get an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: Yeah sure, you indeed answer my question.
I just check your webpage and saw your email and sent you one, I hope you could give it a quick check please.

Again thank you!
Blessings!